# Route53 hosted zone fails redirect to ELB

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have a ELB set and running smooth. It's exposed on internet using URL http://acdd3f11b813911e9b3bf1209a60fe34-1652245676.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/.

If you try to open this link, you'll see a nginx page. I've created a record set inside my hosted zone to run a few tests (nginx.melic.com.br) but it's keep failing and when I try to traceroute I got an error `traceroute: unknown host nginx.melic.com.br`.

Anyone has an idea how to debug what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your DNS zone entries are not accurate. Check the DNS entry for your domain, and make sure you have aliased it with ELB resource host.